# Why does n ^ (2 ** 32 - 1) flip bits?

Tags: python, binary

Was trying to find a solution to this problem had to eventually give up. Can anyone explain why the code below can flip a 0 to 1 and 1 to a 0?

```
00000000000000000000000000000001 ^ (2 ** 32 - 1)
```

OUTPUTS:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
```

Thanks

Comment: What language is this "code" written in?

Comment: First, work out why XORing anything with 1 flips one bit. Then work out why 2^k-1 is a binary number with all bits set to 1. Now you have your answer :-)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't exactly specify it, but for this answer I assume that `**` is the "to the power of" operator and `^` is the XOR operator.

2 ** 32 (2 to the power of 32) is in binary
`100000000000000000000000000000000`

minus 1 is then `011111111111111111111111111111111`

The XOR operator sets each bit to 1 that is not equal in the two operands.

All operations together:

```
2**32 = 100000000000000000000000000000000
   -1 = 011111111111111111111111111111111
  
        011111111111111111111111111111111
  XOR   000000000000000000000000000000001
      = 011111111111111111111111111111110
```

You see that it doesn't depend on how many `0` you have before your numbers, as 0 XOR 0 = 0.

This XOR operation is effectively a NOT for all numbers that do not exceed 32 bits.

Comment: thanks think i get sry for late response been trailing back and forth learning binary again

Answer (score 0):

```
2**32-1 = 11111111111111111111111111111111
1       = 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Since you are XOR'ing the two element-wise, you are comparing where there is a difference in bits.

```
0:1 = 1
1:0 = 1
0:0 = 0
1:1 = 0
```

Since `2**32-1` is all ones, whenever there is a `1` in your second number it will be represented as a `0` in the result. If there is a `0` in your second number, it will be represented as a `1` in the result.